# Angular css selector for custom directive with optional attribute

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors, angular-directive

Lets say I created a custom directive who's selector is `[myCustomDirective]`, this directive has optional input parameter. So it may be used like:

```
<div myCustomDirective></div>
```

or

```
<div [myCustomDirective]="someBooleanFromController"></div>
```

Meanwhile, inside my directive controller I add pseudo class to `elementRef` on which directive is applied.

My question is how my css selector for the directive should look like to be applied no matter if I provide optional attribute for directive or not. 
I tried to use selector like so:

```
[myCustomDirective]:pseudoClassName { 
   // ... some css
}
```

It did the trick when `myCustomDirective` is used without parameter, but it doesn't work in cases when parameter is provided for `myCustomDirective`.

I also tried selector like this:

```
[myCustomDirective="true"]:pseudoClassName { 
   // ... some css
}
```

But it didn't work

Comment: Did you tried my below answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

**HTML**

**app.component.html**

```
<p [appBetterHighlight]="'Yellow'">Highlight with App better directive</p>
```

**CSS**

**style.css**

```
 p[ng-reflect-app-better-highlight] {
    color: blue !important;
 }
```

Here's how the html in interpreted in browser tool

```
<p _ngcontent-c4="" ng-reflect-app-better-highlight="Yellow" style="">Highlight with 
 App better directive</p>
```

The best way to add a CSS to a particular custom directive it to access it in CSS like below:

```
p[ng-reflect-{custom directive name}] { 
    // css here
}
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-directive-1a1sjv?file=styles.css)

Comment: @HostBinding decorator would be a better bet